# gulp sass source map

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I need help adding source map to SASS compiler in the same CSS output folder. Till now, I got to install gulp-sourcemaps module within `gulpfile.js` but couldn't know success to bind `sourcemaps.write` as gulp.task.

Any help is much appreciated :)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var bs = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass'], function() {
    bs.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: "./"
    },
    proxy: {
        target: "localhost:8080", // can be [virtual host, sub-directory, localhost with port]
        ws: true // enables websockets
    }
});
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
        .pipe(bs.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch("scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("*.php").on('change', bs.reload);
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this code for gulp task 'sass':

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
        .pipe(bs.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});
```

First init sourcemaps then compile sass() after that write sourcemap in the same folder ('.')

Regards

Answer (score 8):

I'm using this task since 5 months everyday and works fine,

```
const gulp            = require('gulp'),
      autoprefixer    = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
      plumber         = require('gulp-plumber'),
      sass            = require('gulp-sass'),
      sourcemaps      = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var sassSourcePath = 'YourPath/scss/**/*.scss',
    cssDestPath    = 'YourPath/css/';


gulp.task('sass', () => {

  return gulp
    .src(sassSourcePath)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write({includeContent: false}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({ browser: ['last 2 version', '> 5%'] }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDestPath));

});
```

Also recommend you the `require('gulp-csso')` for the production version

Comment: mine worked after added `{includeContent: false}` inside `sourcemaps.write()`.  Can you explain what that is?

Comment: Hello @weber, if im not mistaken ( old post ) the path by default is `/source/` you must set `includeContent: false` to make possible the custom paths. for further info check the official doc https://github.com/gulp-sourcemaps/gulp-sourcemaps

Answer (score 5):

A complete solution for gulp-sass, map, count all files, minify:

./sass/partial_folders/index.scss

```
@import 'base/_reset';
@import 'helpers/_variables';
@import 'helpers/_mixins';
@import 'helpers/_functions';
@import 'base/_typography';
etc..
```

./gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglifycss = require('gulp-uglifycss');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    return gulp
            .src('sass/**/*.scss')
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
            .pipe(uglifycss({
                "maxLineLen": 80,
                "uglyComments": true
            }))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/'));
});


gulp.task('default', function(){
    gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
})
```